# Открытие ссылок при нажатии на menuStrip C#

Tags: c#, winforms

суть вопроса такова, у меня есть на форме есть `menuStrip` и есть я хочу как только при нажатии на один из пунктов этого меню у меня открывался браузер, и открывалась нужная мне ссылка. Никак не получается реализовать, можете подсказать как это делается, я вообще в этом не соображаю, впервые пользуюсь `menuStrip` , либо же просто можно ссылку на источник где описывается как решить мою проблему, если такое возможно конечно. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавляете обработчик для вашего пункта меню

```
private void openurlToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.google.com"); // заменить URL
}
```

Будет открываться браузер по умолчанию

Добавление: ответ давался для .NET Framework, для .NET Core 3 и выше `Process.Start` может не работать в таком виде. Тогда нужно использовать

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "https://www.google.com", // ваш URL здесь
    UseShellExecute = true
};
Process.Start (psi);
```